# How to find all image tags using Regular Expressions

Tags: php

I need to find all the image html tags that are included in a page using PHP regular expressions

Example

```
<img src="images/image.jpg" />
```

My code

```
preg_match('/<img src=\"images\/.*/',$tags,$matches);
```

The strange thing is it only finds the first occurence, not the rest of the tags in the page

Comment: @Mez - No since not installed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`preg_match_all`](http://de.php.net/preg_match_all). [`preg_match`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) only finds the first occurence, while `preg_match_all` finds all occurrences of the pattern.

Comment: Thx Johann, I can't believe I missed that